# Can't find a way to write a sequence 1,2,3,4,..,K,1,2,3,...,K, where K is user entered number

Tags: java, loops, sequences

This is the loop.

```
    for(m=0; m<10; m++){
        for (i=0; i<=K; i++) {
            A[i] = i;
     }
   }
```

And this is print code.

```
System.out.println("A:");
    for (i=0; i<20; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%.1s\t", A[i]);
        if (i==9) System.out.println();
    }
```

If user enter K as 3 then result is:

```
A:
0   1   2   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

But it should be like

```
A:
0   1   2   3   0   1   2   3   0   1   
2   3   0   1   2   3   0   1   2   3
```

Comment: Hint: Use the modulo `%` operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("A:");
    for (i=0; i<20; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%.1s\t", A[i]%(K+1));
        if (i==9)
          System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loops are wrong. You only altered the first K+1 members of the array.

Answer (score 0):

The index "i" is inside an inner loop so it start from 0 for ech iteration of "m". You are overwriting the first K items of the array A

Maybe you want want write a code like this:

```
ind = 0;
for(m=0; m<10; m++)
{
        for (i=0; i<=K; i++)
        {
            A[indx] = i;
            indx++;
        }
}
```

Comment: minor typo: it should be `indx` not `ind` :)

Answer (score 0):

The order of your numbers is alright, the problem is the Array `A` or better, the index when you add your numbers to that array.

```
for (i=0; i<=K; i++)
     A[i] = i;
```

here you loop through `A` starting at `A[0]` and finishing at `A[K]`. And you do that 10 times:

```
  for(m=0; m<10; m++)
```

So: either you use the `% (modulo)` operator as QBrute suggested in his comment or you find yourself a more "global" index. For example

```
 int j = 0;
 for(int m = 0; m < 10; m++){
    for(i = 0; i <= K; i++){
        A[j++] = i;
    }
 }
```

In this case you have to make sure your array is of the correct size:
You want 10 times the numbers from `0` to `K`, so your `A` would be `int[(K+1)*10]` , while the `+1` is because you loop from `i=0` to `i=K` (which makes `K+1` iterations)

Comment: If I may give you some advices: variables and methods should always start with a small letter (`a` not `A` and `k` not `K`). Then give those variables some useful names like `userInput` instead of `k`, so you will know what they are used for. And lastly:  always use braces `{ }` in `if` statements or `loops`. If you leave out those braces, it may be convenient and faster to write, but it is an unnecessary source for errors. Believe me :) its easier that way

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
    int userEnteredVal = 3;

    Integer[] smallArr = new Integer[userEnteredVal + 1];
    Integer[] outpuptArr = new Integer[20];

    for (int i = 0; i <= userEnteredVal; i++) {
        smallArr[i] = i;
    }

    for (int index = 0; index < 20; index += (userEnteredVal + 1)) {
        System.arraycopy(smallArr, 0, outpuptArr, index, smallArr.length);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < outpuptArr.length; i++) {
        System.out.printf(outpuptArr[i] + "   ");

        if (i == 9) {
            System.out.printf("\n");
        }
    }
```

**OutPut**

```
0   1   2   3   0   1   2   3   0   1   
2   3   0   1   2   3   0   1   2   3
```

hope this will help.